# how should I update paths to global packages like node-inspector when changing versions via NVM?

Tags: linux, node.js, macos, nvm

Related, not an answer: [Managing global npm packages when using nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023792/managing-global-npm-packages-when-using-nvm)

Let's say I install Node 0.12.4 with NVM. Now I want to install `node-inspector` and use it from the command line:

`npm install -g node-inspector`

`Node-inspector` will be placed in: `/Users/[xxx]/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-profiler`

OK no problem. But now when I run `which node-inspector` I get no results. Clearly I need to alias it in `/usr/local/bin` (I think) or add that path to my `$PATH`. But that would mean changing those values when I switch node versions, which doesn't seem in keeping with what nvm is meant to do.

Is there a better way to update the path to any globally installed packages when using nvm and switching versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that would mean changing those values when I switch node versions, which doesn't seem in keeping with what nvm is meant to do.

You'll find a [long discussion of this issue here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/668) which I interpret to contradict your idea of "what nvm is meant to do".

My personal solution has 2 aspects: First, don't install npm modules globally as described [in my blog post here](http://peterlyons.com/problog/2012/09/managing-per-project-interpreters-and-the-path). I find that 95% of my npm libraries that recommend global installation work better with a node version installed courtesy of nvm and tied to the project via a `.nvmrc` file within the project's directory, and project-specific npm modules in the `node_modules` directory within the project. Really, for things like bower, gulp, grunt, stylus, less, browserify, uglify, etc, local install and decent PATH management work just fine.

For things that are really less project specific, I just install a shared node at `~/shared_node.js` and install things in there and put `~/shared_node.js/node_modules/.bin` on my PATH permanently and call it good. At the moment I have just a few things in there like html2jade, keybase, and node-inspector.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the PATH management portion. I'm getting the `Bower: command not found` issue and I'm pretty sure it's because I don't have it on the path correctly.

Comment: Marking as answer just for "First, don't install npm modules globally" -- solid advice, especially in the era of `npx`

Answer (score 0):

i know it's an old question.
but after too much searching i didn't find non dirty way to do.

i'm using fish.
and i just need to add  this kind of path in $PATH

```
/home/{USER}/.nvm/versions/node/{VERSION}/lib/node_modules/bin
```

so i put this in my `config.fish`

```
set PATH $PATH (npm root -g)/bin
```

- if you change your node version. your $PATH will change and you must install those package you want for new version